# Activate Wifi in Acer Travelmate 5742 not using keyboard?

Tags: drivers

I have a Acer Travelmate 5742 laptop where I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate.

Now I can't connecto to Wifi. The laptop has a button to activate/desactivate Wifi but this button is not working and the Wifi is desactivated.

How can I activate the Wifi? I guess I need to download a Driver from Acer, but there many drivers and I can't find the correct one.

[image]

Comment: Is this your keyboard layout exactly? http://www.mega.pk/items_images/310travelmate-5740g-6.jpg

Comment: No, this is my keyboard: http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a605/wmazzola/la-foto_zps16136d79.jpg

Comment: Try installing the **Acer LaunchManager** from http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/drivers

Comment: @BigChris Do you think that if I download and install all the drivers you see in the link picture I'll get it working? http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a605/wmazzola/drivers_zps23443301.png

Comment: Install the drivers AND the Launch Manager and see if it starts to work, yes :)

Comment: ok, I'll try, thnz